# Find the values in a field that has all the values in another field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have this public table on Shakespeare's corpus.

[image]

Now I am looking for the corpus where all three of the words `profession`, `augury`, and `undertakings` exist.

The result should at least have `hamlet`.

How can I do it using legacy sql?

If that is not possible how can I do it using standard sql?

Comment: Sure looks like a lot of repeated data to me.  I question the data design.

Comment: This is just a sample database in google's bigquery. I use it for practicing my concepts about sql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use aggregation:

```
select corpus
from t
where word in ('profession', 'augury', 'undertakings')
group by corpus
having count(distinct word) = 3;
```

I rather religiously avoid legacy SQL, but I think this will work in either version.

Your use of "corpus" is interesting.  I would normally think of a corpus as a set of documents.  What you are looking for is which documents in a corpus contain those three words.

Comment: This solution worked! Thanks!

Do you think there is any other nicer way to do it in standard sql?

Comment: @SyedArefinulHaque . . . I think this is a very nice way to accomplish this.